# Python regex look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Tags: python, html, regex

When trying to extract the title of a html-page I have always used the following regex:

```
(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)
```

Which will extract everything between the  tags in a document and ignore the tags themselves. However, when trying to use this regex in Python it raises the following Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    pattern = re.compile('(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)')
File "C:\Python31\lib\re.py", line 205, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)   
File "C:\Python31\lib\re.py", line 273, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)   File
"C:\Python31\lib\sre_compile.py", line 495, in compile
    code = _code(p, flags)   File "C:\Python31\lib\sre_compile.py", line 480, in _code
_compile(code, p.data, flags)   File "C:\Python31\lib\sre_compile.py", line 115, in _compile
    raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

The code I am using is:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)')
m = pattern.search(f)
```

if I do some minimal adjustments it works:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=<title>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)')
m = pattern.search(f)
```

This will, however, not take into account potential html titles that for some reason have attributes or similar.

Anyone know a good workaround for this issue? Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Is there some reason it has to be a zero-width assertion? Could you just use a non-capturing group?

Comment: Although you shouldn’t use regular expressions to process HTML. Why do you use look-arounds at all and not something like `<title.*>([\s\S]*)</title>` and take the match of the first group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the title tag,

```
html=urllib2.urlopen("http://somewhere").read()
for item in html.split("</title>"):
    if "<title>" in item:
        print item[ item.find("<title>")+7: ]
```

Answer (score 13):

Toss out the idea of parsing HTML with regular expressions and use an actual HTML parsing library instead. After a quick search I found [this one](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html). It's a much safer way to extract information from an HTML file.

Remember, HTML is not a regular language so regular expressions are fundamentally the wrong tool for extracting information from it.

Comment: BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is also a good option.

Answer (score 6):

[Here's a famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on parsing html with regular expressions that does a great job of saying, "don't use regex to parse html."

Comment: Yes and no. You shouldn't use regex to parse an entire DOM, or complicated nestings of tags. However, parsing a single non-nested tag, as the OP is trying to do, is a perfectly legitimate use of regex.

Answer (score 4):

The regex for extracting the content of non-nested HTML/XML tags is actually very simple:

```
r = re.compile('<title[^>]*>(.*?)</title>')
```

However, for anything more complex, you should really use a proper DOM parser like urllib or BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like:

```
 r = re.compile("(<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(</title>)")
 title = r.search(page).group(2)
```