# Using regex in javascript, how to match a string only if another string doesn't come before AND/OR after?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regex in javascript, let's say I want to match `foo`. But I only want to match it if `bar` doesn't come immediately before or after it.

**Matches `foo`**

```
foo
foo bar
bar foo
string foo
stringfoo
foo. string
```

**Does NOT Match `foo`**

```
barfoo
foobar
```

Comment: `(?<!bar)foo(?!bar)` if your regex supports look arounds

Comment: Is it SQL, Go, Google Apps Script, JavaScript, VBA? If not, @anubhava's suggestion will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex negative lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769144/python-regex-negative-lookbehind)

Comment: OP clearly said "in javascript". So negative look-behinds will not work, and an answer in python is **not** a duplicate.

Comment: Apologies for the missing info in my original post. I've updated it to call out javascript specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the simplest regex to do this in *most* languages is with a negative look-behind and a negative look-ahead:

```
(?<!bar)foo(?!bar)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GaLIvL/1)

However, Javascript does not support look-behinds in regular expressions.  Instead, you can mimic the behaviour of a look-behind with a second look-ahead:

```
(?:(?!bar).{3}|^.{0,2})(foo)(?!bar)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gU3ee7/1)

I have placed `foo` in a capture group, in case you actually want to use the value of this match in your real code; if you only care about *whether* the regex matches, rather than *what* the regex matches, then you can replace `(foo)` with just `foo` (no brackets).

The trick is in this part of the regex: `(?!bar).{3}|^.{0,2}`. This is saying "either 3 characters that are not `bar`, or fewer than 3 characters" - which will effectively achieve the same result as a look-behind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookbehinds and negative lookaheads:

```
(?<!bar)foo(?!bar)
```

- Negative lookbehinds follow the syntax `(?<!x)y`. This expression will match `y` if it is not immediately preceded by `x`.
- Negative lookaheads follow the syntax `y(?!x)`. This expression will match `y` if it is not immediately followed by `x`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need this to work in Javascript. And based on the comments above I believe negative lookbehinds will not work. I suppose I'm out of luck?